# how to access parameter of nvim_create_user_command

Tags: lua, neovim

I am writing a lua function as custom command for my neovim config.

As the [documentation](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#nvim_create_user_command) says `"The function is called with a single table argument that contains the following keys"`, but how can i access these keys when the table is not defined to a variable.

I tried calling the function like this:

```
vim.api.nvim_create_user_command('Build', fn_build(args), { nargs='?' })
```

and access the values with:

```
function fn_build(args)
  run = args["args"] or nil
end
```

but i would get a nil error.

---

@Ani commented:

> Try to see if there is anything close to this, in github.com/nanotee/nvim-lua-guide

I found the [guide](https://github.com/nanotee/nvim-lua-guide/blob/master/README.md#defining-user-commands), but it didn't helped me to fix it. I'm not sure if `desc` is the right variable to use. And how would i even use it. The guide says:

> Two additional attributes are available:
>
> 1. desc allows you to control what gets displayed when you run :command {cmd} on a command defined as a Lua callback. Similarly to keymaps, it is recommended to add a desc key to commands defined as Lua functions.
> 2. force is equivalent to calling :command! and replaces a command if one with the same name already exists. It is true by default, unlike its Vimscript equivalent.

---

Am i blind and overseeing something?

Please point me in the right direction

Comment: Try to see if there is anything close to this, in https://github.com/nanotee/nvim-lua-guide

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the function `fn_build` and registering the return value. Instead you should just pass the function as a parameter. Try the following

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_user_command('Build', fn_build, { nargs='?' })
```

Answer (score 1):

fn_build should receive opts as an argument try the following:

```
function fn_build(opts)
    run = opts.args or nil
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As supermeia said your function should receive opts, you should be able to do it directly when you create your command if you don't want to change your `fn_build` function, like this:

```
 vim.api.nvim_create_user_command(
  function(opts)
    fn_build(opts.args)
  end,
  { nargs = '?' }
)
```